# Problem Importing Python Module adafruit_pca9685

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit

I can't figure out how to troubleshoot an import that says it's working, but then obviously is failing.  I'd appreciate any clues where to look.

I'm working on a raspberry Pi, but I'm seeing the same results on my windows machine.  Both running Python 3.7 with Pip 20.

I start by installing the module with pip  `sudo pip3 install adafruit_pca9685`

[image: Request to Install Package]

As you can see it says it's installed correctly.

Then I check that the module is installed with `help('modules')`

[image: List of Modules Installed]

As you can see, it reports that the module isn't there right after it said it installed correctly.

Then I try to import the module with `import adafruit_pca9685`

[image: Module not found]

Then it says that the module isn't found.

What should I be checking next to help solve this?

Comment: Do a filesystem search for file PCA9685.py?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Used find command to search for the file and found it was spelled differently than the tutorial indicated.

Oh man, do I feel dumb...

After suggesting I look for the file, I used `find / -type f -iname "PCA9685.py`.

[image: Looking for the file]

I found the module installed, but it uses capitalization rather than all lower case which is what my documentation was requesting.

After correctly spelling the module name with capitalization, it imports fine.

It's annoying that this module is named in a different format than its sister modules, and annoying that the tutorial was wrong, but I feel dumb for not double checking the spelling.